# How to upload Image using a URL in ReacrJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have to use two image upload options. One is the "Upload Image" button and upload image. The other method is using a URL.

The user will input the URL and an image will be uploaded to the server. I am using ReactJs and Redux toolkit.

I have written code for simple upload using a button

```
           <button
              type="button"
              className="relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-xs font-medium leading-4 text-gray-700 bg-transparent border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm cursor-pointer focus:outline-none dark:text-white"
            >
              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(e) => changeBanner(banner.id, e.target.files[0])}
                accept="image/*"
                className="absolute top-0 left-0 z-50 w-full h-full opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
              />
              <UploadIcon
                className="-ml-0.5 mr-2 h-4 w-4"
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
              Replace a Banner
            </button>
```

Function Implementation:

```
 const changeBanner = (id, file) => {
let data = new FormData();
data.append("id", id);
data.append("file", file);
dispatch(updateBanner(data));
};


  useEffect(() => {
dispatch(fetchBanners());
}, []);
```

**Do anyone know how can we upload an image using an Image URL.?**

```
 <div className="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm b">
                <span className="inline-flex items-center px-3 rounded-l-md border border-r-0 border-gray-300 bg-gray-50 text-gray-500 sm:text-sm">
                  http://
                </span>
                <input
                  type="url"
                  name="company_website"
                  id="company_website"
                  className="flex-1 min-w-0 block w-full px-3 py-2 rounded-none rounded-r-md focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm border-red-300 border-input"
                  placeholder="www.example.com"
                  onChange={handleOnChange}
                />
              </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the backend? Because I'd "upload" the URL and let the server load the image.

Comment: yes I have access to backend

Comment: Cool, so send the URL to the server and let the server load the image.